# is there any way to write one code that works with all possible office documents?

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, translation

I'm writing a program that modifies word documents. Currently I have used Microsoft.Office,Interop.Word to work with Word document and it requiers Microsoft Office to be installed on users computer, but some my clients don't have MS Office, but they have Open Office.
So, which library should I use instead of Interop?

and also how can I make my code to be able to work with different word files, not only .doc and .docx, but also with other office program files?
currently I'm writing different code for every type of the document..

My program translates the documents from its original language to another, so it is very important for me to keep the formatting of the document in original format, that's why I used Interop.. but also I want my program to be useful for as many people as possible

Comment: If you don't want to rely on Office, you'll need to use a 3rd-party implementation in native C#.

Comment: OpenOffice and  Microsoft Office are two different things. What about other company's products?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, I want it to work with different company's products, not only MS Office and Open Office..

Answer (score 3):

I think you are not mentioning but, are you assuming all your clients use the same version of Office. To solve the issue of the office versions, you may want to look at this open source project: NetOffice http://netoffice.codeplex.com/ and do all your .doc and .docx file formats development in using that library.

For the OpenOffice or LibreOffice, I believe the best you can do is going into the projects website and download the SDK. For example, go here: http://api.libreoffice.org/examples/examples.html  and you will find some examples in Java, Python, C++ to edit Text Document including odt files.

LibreOffice SDK download here: http://www.libreoffice.org/download/

And finally, there is also the OpenXML format (mentioned on another answer) which is: 
ECMA Office Open XML ("Open XML") is an international, open standard for word-processing documents, presentations, and spreadsheets that can be freely implemented by multiple applications on multiple platforms.

And you can download also its SDK here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236.aspx

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely end up writing separate code to work with each file type.  There may be *some* similarities within, say, Office products, but for the most part you're going to need an [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for each type.

However, you could (and should) minimize the amount of duplicate code by placing the translation logic and other non-type-specific functions in a shared library that each adapter would then reference.

Answer (score 0):

We are using [aspose words](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx). This supports DOC, DOCX, RTF and OOXML.
But it's not free.